# Kubernetes: define volume mount from different node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have 2 nodes:

- node-0
- node-1.

I created a text file **hello.txt** which contains one line with the content "hello=Dwain" at location /opt/data/index.html. The text file hello.txt was create in the **node-1**.

My default node is **node-0**. I have to create persistentVolume(pv1), persistentVolumeClaim(pvc1) and pod(pod1). In persistentVolume with name pv1 i need to define volume path /opt/data/index.html on the cluster node node-1. Do i need to specify nodeAffinity in persistentVolume, persistentVolumeClaim and pod ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `NodeAffinity` in `PersistentVolumeSpec`.

```
    // NodeAffinity defines constraints that limit what nodes this volume can be accessed from.
    // This field influences the scheduling of pods that use this volume.
    // +optional
    NodeAffinity *VolumeNodeAffinity `json:"nodeAffinity,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,9,opt,name=nodeAffinity"`
```

This `NodeAffinity` will make sure that your `pod` runs in your specific node.

Comment: Add `NodeAffinity` when you are creating `PersistentVolume`

Comment: So when i add nodeAffinity like this i do not have define nodeAffinity in pvc and pod. Am i right ? 
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node-1